# how to convert CVImageBuffer to Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer>?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have this code in Swift and get a error: CVImageBuffer is not convertible to Unmanaged

```
  func getTextureFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) -> GLuint {
    cleanupVideoTextures()
   var unmanagedImageBuffer: Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer> = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)  // Here get the error
    var imageBuffer = unmanagedImageBuffer.takeUnretainedValue()
    var opaqueImageBuffer = unmanagedImageBuffer.toOpaque()
```

How can I cast this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer()` does not take an unmanaged object (anymore? – perhaps that changed
between the beta releases). You can replace

```
var unmanagedImageBuffer: Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer> = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)  // Here get the error
var imageBuffer = unmanagedImageBuffer.takeUnretainedValue()
```

simply by

```
var imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
```

Comment: But then need opaqueImageBuffer for: var cameraFrame: CVPixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(opaqueImageBuffer).takeUnretainedValue()
  textureWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame)
  textureHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)

Comment: @user3745888: Try `var imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) as CVPixelBuffer` and `textureHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)`.